# PHP Passing a variable containing huge text data on form submit

Tags: php, variables, post

Ok, I got a PHP page wherein it reads `a.txt` file (large server log) and stores it in a variable `$logcontents`. I then need to pass that variable to another php page where it will process the `$logcontents` contents accordingly. I am using a form inside the main php page to submit that variable to the other php page, the code is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenlogcontents" value="<?php echo $logcontents ?>">
```

My problem is `$logcontents` when passed to the other php page, it contains only 1 character which is `{`. I'm thinking php can't pass a variable that contains a large amount of data? The first page is able to `echo $logcontents` in the page, it is only when forwarding this variable to another php page that it displays empty or one character. Any ideas? I tried researching but I'm lost of keywords to use for this issue.

Comment: How are you retrieving `$logcontents` ? . Post the code snippet of that.

Comment: What do you have in logcontents before submit ?

Comment: Show us what the resulting HTML looks like here! Also: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: `echo htmlentities($logcontents)`

Comment: Pass the filename and get your second PHP script to read the file.

Comment: passing data with get or post?

Comment: The other (2nd) php page only contain the code " <?php echo $_POST['hiddenlogcontents']; ?> " and the resulting HTML is a blank white page containing only the character "{". The $logcontents is supposed to contain huge server data/log.

Comment: @Rakesh the form method is POST

Comment: @Mike the root page that reads the file takes a while to upload the file then read it's contents to page 1. page 1 now has the variable containing the huge log data. I need it to pass that log data (variable) to page 2 without having it re-upload the file and reading again.:)

Comment: @Mark Baker, what does htmlentities($logcontents) do? It seem to work the way I wanted it to be but it does seem to make another file upload which takes about 20 seconds and which I'm trying to avoid. I though forwarding a large variable wouldn't take another delay

Comment: You're not "forwarding a variable", that is not possible. You're *embedding data in HTML* which the client submits as form data. So yes, it takes another download + upload of the whole thing. Look at the raw HTML of the page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought someone would pick up the slack here, but apparently nobody is...

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenlogcontents" value="<?php echo $logcontents ?>">
```

Since you say the first and only character that gets transmitted is "{", I'll make a lucky guess that the log data consists of JSON strings and looks something like this:

```
{"foo":"bar"...
```

Well, let's interpolate that data into your HTML to see the result of your code snippet:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenlogcontents" value="{"foo":"bar"...">
```

Can you see it here in the SO code highlighter? The value of the `value` attribute is `"{"`. The rest that follows is incorrectly formatted garbage. You're just creating the attribute `value="{"` as far as the HTML parser is concerned.

If you want to embed quotes in HTML attributes, those need to be HTML encoded:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenlogcontents" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($logcontents, ENT_QUOTES); ?>">
```

Please read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

---

Secondarily I'd question how wise it is to transfer huge data blobs this way, forcing the client to download and upload the data repeatedly. But that's another topic...

Comment: A million thanks to you sir for clearing this out, I'm still new at this and wasn't aware the statement considers special characters in it as part of the code instead of variable. Yes it is a JSON and Yes it's most likely that it ignores the rest of the contents because of the double quotes in it. I do want to confirm though, the htmlspecialchars(), like Mark Baker's htmlentities(), seem to do another loading which takes another 20 seconds. So passing a huge amount of data through a variable doesn't happen in a quick way and requires another loading?

Comment: As I commented under the question: yes. You should store the data server-side, maybe in a session.

Comment: Thanks but I may be too much of a noob but when I tried storing it in a PHP session, I can display the session's contents in page 1 but plain blank in page 2. I think my only solution for this is processing the JSON data right after uploading rather than submitting the data to another php page for processing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if is that your issue but encode your $logcontents for url like that :

```
<?php echo urlencode($logcontents); ?>
```

If your text are too long you could short it with encode_base64 :

```
<?php echo base64_encode($logcontents); ?>
```

And use decode_base64 where your retrieve your data :

```
<?php echo base64_decode($logcontents); ?>
```

Hope that could help you ;)

Comment: He's not using the value in a URL, so why `urlencode`?! Base64 incidentally will work, though the functions are named differently. What you're really looking for in the context of an HTML attribute is... drum roll... HTML encoding!

Comment: urlencode because when data have some special char it could break the request header.

Comment: No it couldn't. The data is neither sent in a URL nor in any header. Also, the browser will take care to encode the data accordingly if any of those things were to happen.

Comment: When you use POST it's send into the header data (check debug tool). But you have right the browser are suppose to encode the data (I have confuse with ajax request).

Comment: Nope. POST specifically sends data in **the request body**.

Answer (score -1):

You may close the echo. Try GET to see if the correct value is sent by the URL. If yes,
check your echo command.